# My Keras CNN return the same output value, how can I fix/improve my code

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I've created a code to train my CNN which will determine if a image be one or another class ("pdr or nonPdr")

This is my keras model:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(605,700,3), filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same",activation="tanh"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)

model.fit(np.array(data), np.array(labels), epochs=10, batch_size=16)

model.save('model.h5')
```

And this is my test_predict file:

```py
model = load_model('model.h5')

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

test_image = cv2.imread("test_data/im0203.ppm") 
test_image = test_image.reshape(1,605,700,3).astype('float')
test_image = np.array(test_image)

test_image2 = cv2.imread("test_data/im0001.ppm") 
test_image2 = test_image2.reshape(1,605,700,3).astype('float')

#predict the result
print(model.predict(test_image))
print(model.predict(test_image2))
```

After run the code below I get the same value for my 2 images (that are different, one is pdr and the other is nonPdr)

```
[[0.033681]]
[[0.033681]]
```

How can I fix it and improve my CNN. I appreciate your help.

**Update**
I tried to remove one dense layer and change the last one in a (2, activation='sigmoid') but it not works too.. I really don't have any ideia what to do**

Comment: By PDR you mean "proliferative diabetic retinopathy"?

Comment: Yes thats it....

Comment: When we look at `model.summary()` we can see you'r model has 216million parameter.  You can read this good course to understand how CNN work and how to produce good architecture http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#convert

Comment: + you need to compile model before you load weight. + did you one hot  encoded you'r label?

Comment: 1º I'm compiling in the train file and when I load the model in predict file. Is correct, isn't it? 2º I tried to hot encode but doens't work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of multiple reasons. Most plausible ones are:

1. The input fed to network and the image fed during prediction may not have the same preprocessing steps.
2. The model is over-fitted and when it finds a little different prediction image, it tends to bias its decision based on its training.
3. Model is not good

To avoid such complications, possible future solutions could be:
1. Try feeding a normalized or scaled image only during training and testing.

2. Do not use too many Dense layers (Especially for image classification) because dense layers are good at learning spatial information and for an image to classify correctly, the model needs to look the image in 2d matrix rather than 1d spatial matrix (since dense layers flatten the 2d matrix to 1d matrix).

Even if you are trying to use a dense layer, I would recommend using a dense layer only at the last layer, it, for the final number_of_classes layers. 
A better architecture would be

[ Conv followed by few transition blocks and bottleneck layers ] x 2
flatten
Dense(number_of_classes)

Comment: It not works, I had 0.90(loss) and 0.94(accuracy) and on model.predict continues showing the same value of whatever img.

Comment: Can you show the training images and the test image? You can also email me because I think I can help you out with the prediction part. You can share your colab file. My email: codepk03@gmail.com

Comment: To test, i'm putting one img from each class that had trained.. so the result should be (class one>>>> and class two) but the result is the same.